# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/loginDB

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, netbeans

This has probably already been answered, but I want to know where.
I made a `JFrame`, using NetBeans, and I made a DataBase. I then connected my code, consisting of the `JFrame`, to the DataBase like this:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/loginDB", "loginuser", "userpass");
```

but I keep getting these really long error messages, too long to go on here.
I would like to know how to fix this, and what I'm even doing wrong.

Comment: *"This has probably already been answered, but I want to know where"* - [Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java.sql.SQLException:+No+suitable+driver+found+for+jdbc:derby:&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=8ti5WZfiE9CF4AKGsbegBw)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I already googled it.

Comment: Then, based on your research, how did any of the other proposed solutions not work for you? Did you include the driver Jar in the projects class-path? Did you load the driver's class?